# Structured information about City/Town - Suburb relation in Overpass

Tags: overpass-api

I am trying to get a list of all cities/towns/villages and suburbs of cities/towns in Germany.

I've tried this query :

```
area[name=Deutschland];
 
node[place~"^(city|town|village)$"](area)->.orte;
 
.orte out;
```

The same as CSV:

```
[out:csv(::lon, ::lat, place, name, is_in)];

area[name=Deutschland];

node[place~"^(city|town|village)$"](area)->.orte;

.orte out;
```

Unfortunately the is_in tag is used inconsistent.

How can I get into  `is_in`-column the corresponding name of `place=city` or `place=town` for `suburb` and corresponding name of `place=state` for `city`, `town`, or `village`?

Comment: Overpass is probably not the best choice for this task, better look at geocoders, such as Nominatim instead.

Comment: @mmd According to https://nominatim.org/release-docs/latest/api/Search/ "Special phrases are not suitable to query all objects of a certain type in an area." And it is suggested to use **Overpass API** in this case

Comment: Right, what I meant is that would need to use Nominatim to derive the  "is_in" part of your data, assuming that you have a list of node/way ids you're interested in.